# Why PHP debug(XDebug) isn't working in VScode?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

When I press "Launch current script" I get this error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::9000".
When I changed the port number to a port that I had checked in Command Prompt it's free I still got the same error except with the new port. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
Here is my launch.json file :

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9003
        }
    ]
}
```

Hre is my php.ini file:

```
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9003
zend_extension = D:\XAMPP\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.3-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
```

Debug console:

```
Error: spawn php ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn php',
  path: 'php',
  spawnargs: [ 'd:\\XAMPP\\htdocs\\front controller proba\\proba.php' ]
}
```

Comment: Due to `remote_autostart = 1` maybe?

Comment: Please don't post images of code/error messages. The code/error messages should be included as text and only have images as a clarification if needed. Here you can read why: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)